# An input data format for the BEST2COP utility

Tags: networking, network-traffic

I came across [a research paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2011.05191.pdf), and was wondering if I can use [B2COP-SRG](https://github.com/talfroy/BEST2COP/tree/master/B2COP-SRG) in my research project.
I was able to build the utility from the source code, however, I'm not quite sure how to prepare an input data (a topology graph either as plain text or in a binary format).
To put it differently - I don't know what's the expected data format.

Can somebody help me, please?
Appreciate any clues.
Thank you

Tried: I've complied an utility.
Expecting: a reference in the help section, which exemplifies a step by step manual for preparing a topology graph, which should be supplied as input data to the utility.